# Как корректно получить данные из ячейки?

Tags: mysql, sql

[theme]
[ДОМЕН]

Есть столб "theme" c ячейкой , значение которой "Домен".

```
Как извлечь ее значение ? 
Запрос 
 `SELECT * FROM table  WHERE theme='Домен'`

выдает ошибку
```

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote " was expected. (near "" at position 60)
SQL query:

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Д? LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Ругается только на русские буквы , этот же запрос с латинскими буквами или цифрами работает

Comment: А "LIMIT" в сообщении откуда? Вы нам кусок запроса утаили? Если вызываете запрос из программы, лучше кусок программы приведите. А то хуже будет ;)

Comment: Каюсь , запрос отправлял через phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно установить кодировку (например utf-8)

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```